# request timeout not changing even after changing timeout(windows os)

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am increasing the timeout in the request options, but still, the request is getting timed out after some time(around 100s)

I googled and came to know that, there are two types of timeouts(read timeout and connection timeout). Also, I came to know that, when you increase the timeout greater than the os defined timeout it's not going to work.

Note: I am dealing with high volume data here.

```
request.post('http://192.168.177.132:3001/api',{
    json : {
    stationid : id,
    start : From,
    end : To
    },
    timeout:500000,
    time:true
    },(error, res) => {
    if (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return
    }
})
```

As per the above code, the request should get timed out after 500s, but it's getting timed out at around 100s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your also must increasing the connection timeout of your server (i guess that you has your own server that will receive data from request above).

For example, if your server is Nodejs ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout)), you can increasing the connection timeout like sample below:

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.set('port', port)
// app.get('/upload', ...)

const server = http.createServer(app)

server.timeout = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 24 hours
server.listen(port)
server.on('error', () => { // error handle }))
server.on('listening', () => { console.log('Listening on ' + port) })
```

Each server side language/framework maybe have default timeout, so just increasing it!

Comment: Initially i have express server and i didnt used http.I tried using increasing the express server timeout,but no improvement.Thanks to your answer i tried increasing the http server timeout by installing http and it worked....Thanks a lot